# TypeError: mongodb.db(...).collection(...).find(...).sort is not a function mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I'm trying to sort collection by name and getting this error.

```
handleSortByName = () => {
        const mongodb = Stitch.defaultAppClient.getServiceClient(RemoteMongoClient.factory, 'mongodb-atlas');
        mongodb
            .db('users')
            .collection('userDetails')
            .find()
            .sort({ name: -1 })
            .then((users) => {
                console.log(users);
            })
            .catch((err) => {

                console.log(err);
            });
    };
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Comment: TypeError: mongodb.db(…).collection(…).find(…).sort is not a function

Answer (score 2):

found a solution:

```
.db('users')
            .collection('userDetails')
            .find({}, { sort: { name: -1 } })
            .asArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

use the command:

```
db.collection_name.find(query, projection, options)
```

Here,
query is {},
projection is {}

And so,

```
db.userDetails.find({}, {}, {sort: {name: -1}})
```